# GWT - making GET requests

Tags: gwt

Simple question. I need to make a GET request in GWT *that redirects to a new page*, but I can't find the right API.

Is there one? I am supposed to simply form the URL myself and then do [Window.Location.replace](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html#replace(java.lang.String))?

(The reason is that I want my search page to be linkable)

Thanks.

(and sorry for not making my question clear enough, initially)

Comment: I guess my question boils down to:

How can I have multiple pages using GWT?

Comment: what do you mean "multiple pages"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirecting to a new page is done with Window.Location.replace.

Multiple pages should be handled using the history mechanism.

Answer (score 14):

have a look at 
http://library.igcar.gov.in/readit2007/tutori/tools/gwt-windows-1.4.10/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html

```java
public class GetExample implements EntryPoint {

    public static final int STATUS_CODE_OK = 200;

    public static void doGet(String url) {
        RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);

        try {
            Request response = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
                public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                    // Code omitted for clarity
                }

                public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                    // Code omitted for clarity
                }
            });

        } catch (RequestException e) {
            // Code omitted for clarity
        }
    }

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        doGet("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

GWT does not prohibit you from using regular servlets.

You can declare a servlet in your 'web.xml' file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.myapp.server.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myurl/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and then you can implement your Servlet:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws 
        IOException {

      // your code here

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening a separate window, it is easy:

```
Window.open(url, windowName, "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,location=yes,status=yes");
```

Otherwise, use `RequestBuilder` as Silfverstrom suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Similar with [answer from ivo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/935281/4058484). I can do this in my GWT todomvc frame with `filter mapping` instead of servlet-mapping in `web.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

  <filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myurl/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.todomvc.server.ToDoServerInjector</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <!-- Default page to serve -->
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>GwtGaeChannelToDo.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```